# Gradle change task per subproject?

Tags: gradle

I have a gradle project with multiple subprojects. I'd like to define a "prep" task with a default implementation (e.g. generate a hash, copy a file type of thing), but some subprojects could override with more complicated implementations.

Essentially, some projects are more supporting roles and some contain potential deployables and what "prep" means depends on the subproject.

However, this naive approach does not work where I define the task for all, then try to override it in a subproject. It tells me the task is already defined.

Once upon a time, there was a `tasks.replace()` which might have done the job, but that's been removed from Gradle. How do you do the equivalent now?

```
main build.gradle:
subprojects {
   task prep {
      .. some default behavior
   }
}

subproject build.gradle: 
task prep { 
   .. a subproject specific prep behavior
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Modify task configuration

You can add and modify configuration for existing tasks. The easiest way would be to write:

```
prep {
   // more specific configuration
}
```

It's a shorthand for calling the method `Task.configure()` on the `prep` [`Task`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Task.html) using the [Groovy API](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/groovy_build_script_primer.html#groovy:blocks).

Unfortunately, this does trigger the configuration of the task, which is wasteful if you are not running `prep` on any given build. To keep it lazy so that the configuration is only performed when `prep` is required, you can write:

```
tasks.named('prep') {
    // more specific configuration
}
```

##### What to do then?

The API you then have access to isn't as smooth as overriding a method in a class, but you can do various things to the task ([docs for Task object](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Task.html)):

1. Add additional actions to the base task with `doFirst` and `doLast`;
2. Make deeper changes to the task actions by accessing, removing and modifying the `actions` `List` property (eg `actions.clear()` will remove all existing task actions);
3. Change other task properties upon which the task action depends. This may require separately making or modifying the underlying class defining the task (which would apply to all instances of the task) ([docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_tasks.html)).

So to entirely replace what `prep` does you can write:

```
prep {
   actions.clear()
   doLast {
      // A new task action
   }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't that add to the task, not replace it? In my case, I want to replace what `prep` is doing. The same use case as overriding a method when you extend a class in something like Java.

Comment: I've added more to the answer to explain what you can do when you reconfigure the task.